# single.php only displays the_content()

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am currently learning how to convert a html page to wordpress and trying to do a single.php page. The problem tho is that the page only displays the_content(); When I have a lot of other html and other wordpress functions, why is it that only the get_content(); is the ONLY one showing up on the page?  :

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- Page Header -->
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/post-bg.jpg')">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
        <div class="post-heading">
          <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
          <h2 class="subheading">Problems look mighty small from 150 miles up</h2>
          <span class="meta">Posted by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> on <?php the_time('F j, Y g:i a'); ?></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<!-- Post Content -->
<article>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
        <?php echo "Test echo to see if I get that on the output" ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And The output that I am getting is:

```
<!-- Nav end -->
</nav>
<!-- single.php content -->
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>

<hr>

<!-- Footer -->
<footer>
```

`<!-- Footer -->` displays where the footer.php starts and `<!-- Nav end -->` is where the header.php ends

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Remove header HTML header code you should be add in header.php file

And add following code in single.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- Page Header -->

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<!-- Post Content -->
<article>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
        <?php echo "Test echo to see if I get that on the output" ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: The header html code is a part of the single.php, all pages have a different header for example home.php have one and page.php have another.

Comment: But you already called header file in single.php and for different header you have to create custom header file for this.

Comment: Excuse me, But I do not see how this would solve the problem, as you can see in the top question, nothing except the the_content(); function is being showed in the code not even the html div tags, nor the article tag.

Comment: also the things I have in the header.php is the head and the navigation menu